# SSH into Xen Virtual Machine connection refused

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualization, xen

While practicing for SysAdmin certification, I spun up a virtual machine.  I could not SSH into it from my laptop on my LAN.  I could SSH into the VM from within the host OS. After some reading and running traceroute, I realized that the virtual bridge was on a subnet, so on my laptop I ran ip route add 192.168.122.26 via 192.168.1.101.  Now traceroute yields,

```
 1  192.168.1.101  2.717 ms  2.807 ms  2.780 ms
 2  192.168.1.101  2.782 ms  2.786 ms  3.932 ms
```

Ping 192.168.122.26 yields, `192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable`.  Since the traceroute does not route through my router, I don't suspect my router's firewall is the problem.  I 
suppose the firewall in my host desktop or in the VM could be the problem, but the VM's iptables are empty.

Apparently virt-install no longer saves the domain's configuration in /etc/xen. From my history, the command I used was

```
sudo virt-install --connect xen:// --paravirt -n quark -f /dev/ubuntu-vg/qark -l /vm/OS/debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinsta.iso -r 8192 --vcpus --nographics --os-variant debian9
```

Also, virbr0: inet 192.168.122.1/24, and the host dom0 is Ubuntu 18 LTS with Xen 4.9.

Answer (score 0):

I recalled that iptables doesn't automatically save changes, so I flushed the host OS's rules.  Then I was able to login to my VM directly.  Now I just need to figure out a prudent ruleset for the host OS.  If the edge router is firewalled, I am still unclear as to why each host needs a firewall, but that's a question for another day.